# Debug iPhone app from device crash log

Tags: ios, iphone, logging

I'm trying to debug a hard to reproduce crash on my iPhone app. The only info I have till now is the following log from the device of my customer:

```
Incident Identifier: 7A3417A-4F27-44E3-97A3-AF811A79C88E
CrashReporter Key:   13d8ee7a1052506be1ae7b4bbcb3439d1c86df85
Hardware Model:      iPhone4,1
OS Version:          iPhone OS 6.0 (10A403)
Kernel Version:      Darwin Kernel Version 13.0.0: Sun Aug 19 00:28:05 PDT 2012; root:xnu-2107.2.33~4/RELEASE_ARM_S5L8940X
Date:                2012-10-24 08:11:29 +0200
Time since snapshot: 7156 ms

Free pages:        793
Active pages:      3323
Inactive pages:    2043
Throttled pages:   88283
Purgeable pages:   144
Wired pages:       33372
Largest process:   NLinBusiness

Processes
     Name                                           rpages       recent_max       [reason]          (state)

             lsd           172              172         [vm]         (daemon) (idle)
     MobilePhone          1015             1015         [vm]         (resume) (continuous)
            tccd           170              170         [vm]         (daemon)
    NLinBusiness         51246            51246         [vm]         (frontmost) (resume)
      calaccessd           288              288                      (daemon)
    mediaserverd          2319             2319                      (daemon)
           wifid           570              570                      (daemon)
       locationd          1312             1312                      (daemon)
         syslogd           171              171                      (daemon)
      aosnotifyd           684              684                      (daemon)
     dataaccessd          2504             2504                      (daemon)
   iaptransportd           235              235                      (daemon)
     SpringBoard         23545            23545                     
      backboardd          5779             5779                      (daemon)
        networkd           210              210                      (daemon)
        BTServer           240              240                      (daemon)
         configd           804              804                      (daemon)
   fairplayd.N94           161              161                      (daemon)
       fseventsd           499              499                      (daemon)
         imagent           703              703                      (daemon)
   mDNSResponder           306              306                      (daemon)
  UserEventAgent           601              601                      (daemon)
    mediaremoted           225              225                      (daemon)
           amfid           136              136                      (daemon)
   syncdefaultsd           294              294                      (daemon)
             ubd           456              456                      (daemon)
        recentsd           859              859                      (daemon)
        SCHelper           146              146                      (daemon)
        twitterd           636              636                      (daemon)
   absinthed.N94           104              104                      (daemon)
         sociald           885              885                      (daemon)
filecoordination           202              202                      (daemon)
       distnoted           129              129                      (daemon)
            apsd           348              348                      (daemon)
      aggregated           103              103                      (daemon)
       lockdownd           349              349                      (daemon)
          powerd           189              189                      (daemon)
       securityd           389              389                      (daemon)
      CommCenter          1045             1045                      (daemon)
         notifyd           210              210                      (daemon)
     ReportCrash           332              332                      (daemon)

**End**
```

Is there any useful info about the crash in this log?

Answer (score 9):

Actually, this log is quite informative. The app in question didn't crash - it was killed by Jetsam/memorystatus. This was explained by us in [My app crashes and closes down and there is very little information as to why](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13152502/my-app-crashes-and-closes-down-and-there-is-very-little-information-as-to-why/13160021#13160021)

In your case, the NLinBusiness app (yours, I guess?) is using *way* too much memory - remember that iOS has no swap. The free page count is low so as to trigger a low memory condition, and your app is killed. By responding to Low Memory Events, you can stave off being killed.

Answer (score 0):

This log won't help you at all. It does not contain anything specific to your code. For getting an info in a log file look at this link

http://cocoaforbreakfast.wordpress.com/2011/02/25/logging-into-files-for-ios/

Comment: it won't help you at all if you don't know how to read it. But then, that is true of many things.