# Couldn't understand the iOS crash report

Tags: ios, crash, crash-reports

When I was testing my iOS app in the device, the app crashed for some reason. When I check the report, this is what I got it

```
Incident Identifier: 28CD702E-A618-4B0A-90CC-C385644D1228
CrashReporter Key:   e1aaea05f2b1b5c9047758ba0b0a107de8f7c015
Hardware Model:      iPod4,1
OS Version:          iPhone OS 6.1.3 (10B329)
Kernel Version:      Darwin Kernel Version 13.0.0: Wed Feb 13 21:36:52 PST 2013; root:xnu-2107.7.55.2.2~1/RELEASE_ARM_S5L8930X
Date:                2013-09-19 20:28:37 +0530
Time since snapshot: 84 ms

Free pages:        692
Active pages:      1478
Inactive pages:    1000
Throttled pages:   47938
Purgeable pages:   0
Wired pages:       12517
Largest process:  MyApp

Processes
     Name                    <UUID>                       rpages       recent_max       [reason]          (state)

      MobileMail <e07ca7a7280736c7bf301451f89d1c02>          984              984         [vm]         (resume) (continuous)
     MobilePhone <51866c9bc9f93c9d8526e8acf9efc64c>          918              918         [vm]         (resume) (continuous)
            tccd <2778744d99a530c9a7d5e57a19b60008>          145              145         [vm]         (daemon)
             kbd <f7341c9a161a39acb5bc18ea47d6ebb7>          384              384         [vm]         (daemon)
           MyApp <3969fa455e063bd3b085abac48006467>        34001            34001         [vm]         (frontmost) (resume)
            ptpd <096297a7a40f318290a972274cc44d87>          632              632                      (daemon)
      calaccessd <eacfa291553f369ab61c8cc49d5059f6>          255              255                      (daemon)
     dataaccessd <abc7f74d5d683d4c9a04e7ade5b1126b>          749              749                      (daemon)
    itunesstored <44d1bc6b3088390bb5c58d052a71f8f2>         1192             1192                      (daemon)
           wifid <72eda25ccdd737a79d6cd172e9bf99a5>          294              294                      (daemon)
   iaptransportd <9b3cf56b4db13761bbd8ac2e0ff099be>          228              228                      (daemon)
         syslogd <da215e2d3de133bf8f52590727b9bdfe>          274              274                      (daemon)
    mediaserverd <af72564bf8713fb8b16ee64c5ee85568>         1174             1174                      (daemon)
       locationd <137100f254373daeb894f665c413f8b0>          667              667                      (daemon)
     SpringBoard <bd1d77d154ef3dffbb53d89337c8a08f>         2594             2594                     
      backboardd <e1dc74434e0e3938b17ff0f7ad85d138>         3588             3588                      (daemon)
            apsd <5be27dc5ea5234319bc4b47380e42174>          350              350                      (daemon)
filecoordination <28ca39773e933ed2aa92c117c661d056>          144              144                      (daemon)
      aggregated <c5a375854c3c31d59548ab53ea86d194>           79               79                      (daemon)
            afcd <3bd960d39c9f3972a10923db0e687b4a>          133              133                      (daemon)
        networkd <49064febbe553338bd98051399022da4>          187              187                      (daemon)
       fseventsd <3ea853cb95de3aa48972aa42637af69a>          254              254                      (daemon)
        BTServer <af0150d5085e326598edff072a23d146>          299              299                      (daemon)
         imagent <2b64c6111aa63b179a15afd6a76a6696>          331              331                      (daemon)
         configd <b6a4d70640b63e8f82e0e9f3d6ee2bb9>          407              407                      (daemon)
notification_pro <08df322fbe7739199f78852a511169ef>          148              148                      (daemon)
       lockdownd <a123aa04ddf83a5fae8e5bc08f0b5771>          243              243                      (daemon)
          powerd <63673a83ac9c3cf98fdc75df8ba70fd0>          136              136                      (daemon)
         DTPower <2e44c0d9de4d3faa8a2242fa684a5370>          266              266                      (daemon)
    syslog_relay <ee47daae952636649230d38b3dc5c2e0>            0                0                      (daemon)
   mDNSResponder <1e651badfb7033a68a73a667ec480a08>          270              270                      (daemon)
  UserEventAgent <7ee3410c25e4372d84e93318fe42696b>          406              406                      (daemon)
       distnoted <699b8253736233b29180419f139e8c01>          115              115                      (daemon)
springboardservi <438ae856a1c039a197e6987a99a8b9b6>            0                0                      (daemon)
     debugserver <befb5a346ad43ac1be6790ab46eaceff>            0                0                      (daemon)
   fairplayd.N81 <77e375dae58c351aab5a79484c487bd7>          143              143                      (daemon)
    mediaremoted <ecae0f5d9a023c45ab885f2e02db6138>          212              212                      (daemon)
         notifyd <67a17b0c297e3785a9e09b8e72f3636a>          151              151                      (daemon)

**End*
```

*

I cannot understand what this report says, It says myapp is the largest process. Can I know what it mean and what is cause of this issue?

Thanks

Comment: @incmiko How does adding random code help answer this question? Did you look at the crash report? This is a crash due to too much memory. This is not a typical app crash report with a stack trace.

Comment: @nkd Your app is using too much memory. Use Instruments to figure out any memory leaks and/or referece cycles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like your leaking memory like crazy.
I would run instruments both in leaks mode and in general mode to see the real memory footprint.

This is a general crash log as you noticed - not an app specific crash log - which means you really stressed the device.

Try running it in debug - I bet you do some allocation in a loop. the crash while connected to a debugger should be more obvious and perhaps even see the loop event if it crashes on failing to allocate more memory.

Comment: Thanks, I will run the instruments to see where the memory is shooting.

Answer (score 2):

Your app has been closed because of memory issue.

See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13152502/my-app-crashes-and-closes-down-and-there-is-very-little-information-as-to-why) for more detailed information.