# “JetsamEvent-2015-03-18-151504.ips” files are generated for crashes instead of .crash files

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad

IN iOS 8.2 Device, my application got crashed,So to see the crash logs i connected my device to Mac (Xcode->devices->Device logs)
.There were no crash(.Crash) files generated instead “JetsamEvent-2015-03-18-151504.ips” files were generated which were of no use.And i am also using PLCrashReporter framework to collect crashes , but it is also not helpful in finding these crash files.Do anyone know why the crash file was not generated for my app crash?
Anyone have face this issue.

Thank you.

Answer (score 8):

JetsamEvent log is so called Low Memory Report.
So, it is highly possible that your App was killed by system due to memory shortage.

References
- [My app crashes and closes down and there is very little information as to why](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13152502/my-app-crashes-and-closes-down-and-there-is-very-little-information-as-to-why/)
- [Understanding Low Memory Reports (*a little bit outdated)](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2151/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008184-CH1-UNDERSTANDING_LOW_MEMORY_REPORTS)