# Codename One application works on simulator and Android but crashes on iPad and iphones

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, codenameone

My codename one app, works fine on Android and on the simulator, but on my iPad it doesn't. I've tested on iPad and iPhone devices, and it crashes.

On the iPad (iPad3,4), I see `JetsamEvent` events generated after the crash.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29119276/jetsamevent-2015-03-18-151504-ips-files-are-generated-for-crashes-instead-of) seems to indicate that it is a memory problem, but I'm experiencing the issue only on Apple devices (iPad and iPhone).

Anyone have any suggestion to manage or improve the memory of my app?

In all kind of Android devices that I tested, the application never crashed like this.

The crash is always aleatory. After the crash, I repeat the same actions and it doesn't crash. It's totally random.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's unclear to me if the crash is immediately on startup or at some other point. Regardless I would suggest covering the basic functionality that you invoked which might give some clues as to what went wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of test, I find out that the problem is in the mapResponse object and how it works in the iOS systems.
If the mapResponse is small, you can do this: 
`String resResponse=(String)mapResponse.get("RES");` with no problem in iOS.

But if the response is big (4000 characters for example), the `mapResponse.get("RES")` is not a true String. Only work with that false String object crash the application, for example:

```
if (resResponse != null && resResponse.startsWith("SUP"))
```

So I have to check if the mapResponse Object is String or not like this:

```
isError=(objResp instanceof String)
```

Answer (score 0):

There isn't much to be done with crash reports like that, I suggest using the `Log` class to track where the crash actually happened and using the process of elimination to figure out which piece of code is responsible for the crash.

Comment: After a lot of test, I find out that the problem is in the mapResponse object and how it works in the iOS systems.
If the mapResponse is small, you can do this: String resResponse=(String)mapResponse.get("RES"); with no problem,

But if the response is big, only manage the String object crash the application:
if (resResponse != null && resResponse.startsWith("SUP"))

So I have to check if the mapResponse Object is String or not like this:
isError=(objResp instanceof String)