# Application received Memory warning: Memory level is not normal or this app was killed by jetsam

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, memory-leaks, instruments

My Application is received Memory warning and got this Message in Console in device.

> **Memory level is not normal or this app was killed by jetsam.**

I also try to find solution in **instruments via leak and memory allocation** but could not find anything needful.

Comment: is your app crash when you received the memory warning?

Comment: Your app is using too much memory. Have a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13160021/908621, it will probably help you.